# how to use next-redux-wrapper on next JS 13?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

i'm using the app dir in next js 13 and redux. i have multiple redux reducers so i needed to combine them using `next-redux-wrapper` package. when using the old way with `export default wrapper.withRedux(RootLayout);` it works but not for other browsers. and it shows a warning `/!\ You are using legacy implementaion. Please update your code: use createWrapper() and wrapper.useWrappedStore().`. so i updated the code in my `layout.js`.

```
"use client";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { wrapper } from "../store";

function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const { store } = wrapper.useWrappedStore();
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ChakraProvider>{children}</ChakraProvider>
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
export default RootLayout;
```

but when i use this it show there is an error on `const { store } = wrapper.useWrappedStore();` line `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialState')`. so how can i use redux with Next JS 13?

`store.js`

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import menuReducer from "./slices/menuSlice";
import livingReducer from "./slices/livingSlice";
import {} from "react-redux";
import { ActionTypes } from "@mui/base";
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  menu: menuReducer,
  living: livingReducer,
});

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (ActionTypes.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload,
    };
    return nextState;
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
  }
};
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducer,
});

const makeStore = () => store;

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

please any help

Answer (score 2):

> This library will not work with new app structure. In fact, app structure makes redux usage really awkward and I do not recommend to do it. Since any server component can dispatch actions on server side, we will have to constantly sync redux state from server to client, which I find awkward.

kirill-konshin (creator of this package). Please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/494) on github

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [source code for useWrappedStore](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/blob/8.x/packages/wrapper/src/index.tsx#L214), it is expecting the initial state to be passed into the function call. Something like this:

```js
const { store } = wrapper.useWrappedStore({ initialState: { foo: "bar" } });
```

This should fix your error.